# Android Lollipop の OpenGL で、 glDrawArrays() 呼び出しがクラッシュする

Tags: android, opengl-es

Android Lollipop に対応する実装を行っています。

KitKat までは異常無く動作するのですが、 Lollipop でアプリ起動時した場合にクラッシュしてしまいます。

Log を追ってみた所クラッシュは OpenGL 関数内 `glDrawArrays()` 呼び出しで起こっていました。

```java
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, ver);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, color);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);  // crash
glPopMatrix();
```

を呼び出した時にクラッシュしています。KitKat までになかった WARNING です。

```
WARNING: Couldn't find glCurrentPaletteMatrixOES in procAddrs table
WARNING: Couldn't find glLoadPaletteFromModelViewMatrixOES in procAddrs table
WARNING: Couldn't find glMatrixIndexPointerOES in procAddrs table
WARNING: Couldn't find glWeightPointerOES in procAddrs table
```

検索を行った所、他に全く例がありませんでした。

ご存知の方、解決方を教えて頂けないでしょうか。  
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: クラッシュが発生するのはエミュレータ／実機／両者でしょうか？（エラーメッセージ的にはGLES下層ライブラリ内で一部関数定義が存在しないと警告しているようです）

Comment: >yohjpさん
コメントありがとうございます。
クラッシュを確認したのは実機のみです。エミュレータでのテストは行っておりません。

私も定義されていないのかなと思ったのですが、他の関数でglDrawArrays()を呼び出すと通常通り動作を行う事ができてしまい原因不明の状態になっていました。

Comment: >user3009331さん
コメントありがとうございます。
教えて頂いたチェック方法確認します。現在私のアプリではOpenGL1.0を使用しています。

Answer (score 1):

ソースコードを拝見したところOpenGL ES 1.Xだと思いますが、
1.XはLollipopだとクラッシュするという報告が多数上がっているようです。
英語版stackoverflowにも多数質問がありますね…

Androidのバージョンアップで改修されるのを待つか、OpenGL ESの上位のバージョンでプログラムし直すしかないと思います。

Answer (score 0):

glDrawArraysが呼び出された時点で必要なパラメータが初期化されていない可能性があります。
Warningに記載してある関数が使われている場所の記載がないのでなんとも言えませんが、Matrix関係の値に不正な値が入っているような感じがします。
該当Extensionをデバイスが正式サポートしているかをもう一度確認したほうが良いと思います。
また各gl関数がエラーをセットしていないか確認するのも手がかりになると思います。